# My nodejs application threw OOM error, who can help me?

Tags: node.js, oom

This is the error detail:

```
2023-05-15 21:55:12
content:
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1863547:0x5620b40] 378729271 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1636.1 (1993.4) -> 1636.1 (1946.6) MB, 413.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.796, current mu = 0.054) last resort; GC in old space requested
[1863547:0x5620b40] 378729752 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1636.1 (1946.6) -> 1636.0 (1930.6) MB, 480.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.639, current mu = 0.000) last resort; GC in old space requested
```

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb6b850 node::Abort() [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 2: 0xa806a6  [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 3: 0xd52140 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 4: 0xd524e7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 5: 0xf1dd1f v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 6: 0xefdcb8 v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::AllocateCode(bool) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 7: 0xf11bfc v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::BuildInternal(bool) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 8: 0xf1269e v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::Build() [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
 9: 0x15ca57e v8::internal::RegExpMacroAssemblerX64::GetCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
10: 0x128f096 v8::internal::RegExpCompiler::Assemble(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::RegExpMacroAssembler*, v8::internal::RegExpNode*, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
11: 0x12aefd7 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Compile(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::RegExpCompileData*, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::RegExpFlag, int>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool, unsigned int&) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
12: 0x12af752 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
13: 0x12b030e v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
14: 0x12b04b3 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::RegExpMatchInfo>, v8::internal::RegExp::ExecQuirks) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
15: 0x12d584e v8::internal::Runtime_RegExpExec(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
16: 0x16ef479  [/usr/local/nodejs/bin/node]
```

Do not report the OOM exception before the memory threshold is reached, but it happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are doing everything correct in terms of application.
Looking at your code might help.

A helpful tip and not a silver bullet is to use `--max-old-space-size=`